# Представить массив в виде таблицы

Tags: python

У меня есть типа массив, мне нужно представить его в виде таблицы. Как это сделать?

```
import random
random.seed()
m = input() # количество рядков
n = input() # количество столбцов
print([[random.randint(-100, 100) for _ in range(eval(m))] for _ in range(eval(n))])
```

Comment: В этом коде нет никакого массива, есть просто набор чисел, которые печатаются один раз. PS. eval не требуется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import random
random.seed()
m = input('Количество столбцов > ') # количество столбцов
n = input('Количество строк > ') # количество рядов
M = [[random.randint(-100, 100) for _ in range(eval(m))] for _ in range(eval(n))]
for V in M:
    for e in V:
        print(e, end=', ')
    print()
```

Вывод:

```
85, -79, 30, -4, -68,
56, -69, -57, -48, 77,
49, 88, -68, 29, -87,
```

Если нужен более структурированный вывод (с табуляциями), можно использовать библиотеку `Pandas`

P.s. `m` и `n` были местами перепутаны. `m` - столбцы, `n` - строки. Если обязательно наоборот - в генераторе поменяй их местами.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать стандартный модуль `pprint` - хорошо помогает красиво отображать разные сложные структуры данных с большим количеством уровней вложенности:

```
import random
random.seed()
m = input() # количество рядков
n = input() # количество столбцов

from pprint import pprint

pprint([[random.randint(-100, 100) for _ in range(eval(m))] for _ in range(eval(n))])
```